# SAP Smartforms layout trouble with packed numbers

Tags: abap, sap-smart-forms

I'm currently trying to fill a smartform with some information. I have a simple text element and read the data fields via `&name&`. The data itself gets read perfectly fine, however the layout is incorrect. Some fields are just plain text, and others are defined as packed numbers with 2 decimals. These packed number fields for some reason are out of alignment, always showing one line below everything else that is supposed to be in this line. That looks like that:

[image]

How can I get the 121,08 in this example on the same height as the rest? The text element looks like the following:

```
test               &field1&     &field2& &field3&
```

Only field 2 is a packed number, therefore I think it might have something to do with that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use as below. C will remove extra space.

&field2(C)& &field2(C)& &field3(C)&

Comment: [List of formatting options](https://help.sap.com/saphelp_nw70/helpdata/en/1c/f40c6fddf311d3b574006094192fe3/frameset.htm)